# Transaction not working for sub functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, transactions

I've  using `DB::beginTransaction()` in Laravel but its working only for database changes that done in main function only not for sub functions.

**Main function code:**

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $data = array(
        'id' => Input::get('id'),
        'task_title' => Input::get('task_title'),
    );
    DB::table('task')->insert($data);
    $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    // Add Actionees
    if (!$this->addActionees(Input::get('actionees'), $id)) {
        DB::rollback();
        return Response::json(false);
    }
    DB::commit();
    return Response::json(true);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    DB::rollback();
    return Response::json($ex);
}
```

**Sub function Code:**

```
private function addActionees($actionees, $id, $status) {
    try {
        DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 
        foreach ($actionees as $act) {
            $actAdd = array(
                'task_id' => $id,
                'user_id' => $act->user_id,
            );
            DB::table('task_assignee')->insert($actAdd);
        }
        return True;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

So in above example the changes that done under functions `addActionees()` is not rolled back ,In function `addActionees()` all record against ID will removed before inserting new records. If there is exception found then i want to revert these changes.

Comment: Could you paste these two functions? `addTasks()` and `addActionees()`

Comment: Seems both function returning `true` even in error case.

Comment: No the returning false but DB::rollback() not working for changes that done under addTasks()

Comment: To rollback a transaction, shouldn't you commit the transaction first?

Comment: @GovindSamrow have you tried the first example here? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions  that is handing rolling back of commit by itself

Comment: Yes, but it's not working in case of sub functions

Comment: What's your database? MySQL? And what's the default engine of it?

Comment: Using MySql with 'InnoDB' engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the whole transaction inside a closure - [it will handle everything for you](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions):

```
public mainFunction()
{
    try {
        DB::transaction(function() {
            $id = DB::table('task')->insertGetId(['id' => Input::get('id'),
                                                  'task_title' => Input::get('task_title')]);

            DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 

            foreach(Input::get('actionees') as $act) {
                DB::table('task_assignee')->insert(['task_id' => $id,
                                             'user_id' => $act->user_id]);
            }
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         return Response::json($e);
    }

    return Response::json(true);
}
```

*p.s. I also refactored your code as it was driving me crazy. This should work, but I havent tested it - but you get the general idea.*

Comment: Are you adding any others than what is listed? If you take the 3 lines of code out of the sub function and just place them in the main function - does it work then?

Comment: I think this code should work in my experience. @Laurence What's your database and dose it support transaction?

Comment: @yixiang - I think you meant Govind Samrow - not me

Comment: @Laurence Oh, yeah, sorry i made a mistake :)

Comment: Transaction works when I've used it in sub function separately.

Comment: @GovindSamrow - try my code now - does *that* work? I find it strange the sub function doesnt work?

Comment: Thanks @Laurence got the problem, after this code transaction still not working for a table  and after further investigate I've found there is table with different data engine.

Answer (score 2):

You should not catch the exception in addActionees() method. Just leave it thrown and the outer try-catch block will handle it:

Main function code:

```
try {
  DB::beginTransaction();
  $data = array(
    'id' => Input::get('id'),
    'task_title' => Input::get('task_title'),
  );
  DB::table('task')->insert($data);
  $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

  // Add Actionees
  $this->addActionees(Input::get('actionees'), $id);
  DB::commit();
  return Response::json(true);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  DB::rollback();
  return Response::json($ex);
}
```

**Sub function code:**

```
private function addActionees($actionees, $id, $status) {
        DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 
        foreach ($actionees as $act) {
            $actAdd = array(
                'task_id' => $id,
                'user_id' => $act->user_id,
            );
            DB::table('task_assignee')->insert($actAdd);
        }
}
```

Comment: Already tried this but not working, its not reverting changes that done in `addActionees`

Comment: Just for your informations its working for sub functions (`addActionees()` )

Answer (score 0):

In Main function : `beginTransaction` bofore `try{`

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
$data = array(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Its only works when use `DB::beginTransaction()` in sub function too but its not a answer of my question:

**Main function code:**

```
try {
  DB::beginTransaction();
  $data = array(
    'id' => Input::get('id'),
    'task_title' => Input::get('task_title'),
  );
  DB::table('task')->insert($data);
  $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

  // Add Actionees
  if (!$this->addActionees(Input::get('actionees'), $id)) {
    DB::rollback();
    return Response::json(false);
  }
  DB::commit();
  return Response::json(true);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  DB::rollback();
  return Response::json($ex);
}
```

**Sub function Code:**

```
private function addActionees($actionees, $id, $status) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 
        foreach ($actionees as $act) {
            $actAdd = array(
                'task_id' => $id,
                'user_id' => $act->user_id,
            );
            DB::table('task_assignee')->insert($actAdd);
        }
        DB::commit();
        return True;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use transaction through the flow like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    $data = array(
        'id' => Input::get('id'),
        'task_title' => Input::get('task_title'),
    );
    DB::table('task')->insert($data);
    $id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

    // Add Actionees
    $this->addActionees(Input::get('actionees'), $id);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    DB::rollBack();
    return Response::json($ex);
}

DB::commit();
return Response::json(true);

private function addActionees($actionees, $id, $status) {
    DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 
    foreach ($actionees as $act) {
        $actAdd = array(
            'task_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $act->user_id,
        );
        DB::table('task_assignee')->insert($actAdd);
    }
}
```

1. Begin transaction.
2. Execute CRUD operations.
3. Catch exception and rollback the transaction.
4. If the operations executed smoothy, commit the transaction.

**Edit:**

The `addActionees` always return true because of the `delete()` method doesn't throw an exception while executed failed. Therefore `$this->addActionees(Input::get('actionees'), $id)` always return true.
Let's throw an exception manually:

```
private function addActionees($actionees, $id, $status) {
    $deleteResult = DB::table('task_assignee_user')->where('task_id', $id)->delete(); 
    foreach ($actionees as $act) {
        $actAdd = array(
            'task_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $act->user_id,
        );
        DB::table('task_assignee')->insert($actAdd);
    }

    if ($deleteResult  == 0) {
        throw new Exception('Delete failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you haven't read the ques, transaction is working but its not roll baking the changes that done under `addActionees()` function

Comment: Is the code `DB::rollback()` been executed or we can say is the exception been catched?

Comment: Yes `DB::rollback()` is working but only for main function